Citations to published literature for the profiniteness of Inn(G) for G a profinite group
A recent question asked whether the inner automorphism group of a profinite group is profinite, and received an answer which was mathematically unimpeachable:  yes because (1) the center is always a closed normal subgroup and (2) quotienting a profinite group by a closed normal subgroup always results in a profinite group.  Unfortunately the citations for both of those facts, neither of which are that hard to prove, was to other StackExchange posts.
Writing out the proof, easy though it is, in a paper I (and the previous questioner, Alex Bayard, and three other coauthors) are writing would be a distraction from the point of the paper.  Google Scholar and checking the books on profinite groups my university library has have been useless.  Surely there are published papers or books containing either the result itself or proofs of (1) and (2) that can be cited so we don't need to write out a proof.
Any help, ideally pointing to the specific theorem or proposition within the paper or book, would be much appreciated.
